# Force.com Toolkit for .NET class construct with QueryAsync when SQL query has a child/parent relationship

Tags: .net, toolkit, soql, force.com

I'm running the following query which contains a child => parent relationship between Case and Account - and contains the Account.Name in the SELECT:

```
string query = "SELECT Case.CaseNumber,Case.Account.Name,Case.Status FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Closed' AND OwnerId IN (SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = '" + userEmail + "') ORDER BY Account.Name";
var results = await client.QueryAsync<CaseWorkload>(query);
```

The `CaseWorkload` class is defined as:

```
public class CaseWorkload
{
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

I am unable to retrieve the `AccountName` information as the returned SQL shows `Account.Name` and I couldn't find a way in SOQL to alias a column. How should the class be created considering the given query?

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following to get the Account Name - then of course you can map the Account Name to a property in `CaseWorkload` if desired:

```
public class CaseAccount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CaseWorkload
{
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public CaseAccount Account { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what about if you have a waterfall relationship?

Example:
public class CaseAccount
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
        public User Owner { get; set; }
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class CaseWorkload
{
  public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
  public string Status { get; set; }
  public CaseAccount Account { get; set; }
}

The User objects are never filled from the return of this query.

I am adding 
CreatedBy.Name, CreatedBy.Phone, Owner.Name, 
Owner.Phone in the query.

Using Postman I see the result of the query is working fine.